# Visual Studio Shortcut to select an entire line

Tags: visual-studio

I often find myself selecting entire lines in visual studio usually for correcting indents.

Using home->shift+end doesn't select the whitespace at the beginning of the line, so pressing tab will replace the selection with a tab, instead of indenting.

Is there a hotkey to select the entire line in visual studio?

Comment: For intending you don't have to select the line

Comment: Double tap Home, to have the cursor start from Col[0]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any shortcut to select the current line in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159398/is-there-any-shortcut-to-select-the-current-line-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 8):

hit <kbd>home</kbd> twice before you hit <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>end</kbd> to select the whole line plus tabs

Or my preferred method is start from the end and type

<kbd>end</kbd> -> <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd>

As for correcting tabs, if you select more than 1 line it will tab out all lines, but selecting only 1 line will replace that line with a tab (whether you select the current tabs along with it or not).  To tab a single line don't highlight the line at all:

<kbd>home</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: Are you telling me in VS there's no equivalent for [simple CTRL + L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406964/how-do-i-select-a-single-line-within-visual-studio-code/50407066#50407066) of Atom, Sublime Text, VS Code and who knows what other editors?