# How do I select a single line within Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Using Microsoft's Visual Studio Code, how do I select a single line of code? (equivalent to Atom's or other IDE's <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Mac)

And what would be the command I'm looking for? (e.g. `editor.action.copyLinesDownAction`)

It's quite confusing, since other selection shortucts like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> are the same as in my previous IDE's.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It's <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> by default in VS Code versions prior to 1.32.

Starting from version [1.32](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_32#_default-keybinding-change-for-expandlineselection) it's <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

You could change it in Keyboard Shortcuts by searching for `expandLineSelection`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the default value changed to `CMD`/ `CTRL` + `L` in vscode 1.32.1

Comment: Why did they change it?

Comment: Cmd + L doesn't work for me, I guess there's some collision.

Comment: CTRL + L doesn't work after version 1.32. But you can go in shortcuts and search for expandLineSelection and change that shortcut from CTRL + L to CTRL + I. Now It works.

Comment: If you have Live Server Extension, it will create collision and `CMD` + `L` will not work.
For `CMD` + `L` to work, either modify the shortcuts of Live Server or delete it.

Comment: @KrishnaPravin YES thank you this was my issue! Finally `CMD + L` works for me

Comment: This select current line _and the first character of the next line_ which is very undesirable when e.g. pasting somewhere.

Answer (score 39):

As for me, I noticed that what was causing the issue was that there were similar keyboard shortcuts. As a result, what fixed it was deleting the similar keys.

So when I tried to use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> I noticed that there was this thing in the left corner.

Picture that says it is awaiting an actual command:

[image: picture that says it is awaiting an actual command]

So what I did was simply delete the commands in the keyboard shortcut (i.e. <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) that were similar. They ended up being shortcuts for the live server extension.

You can see which ones are similar by typing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in the search bar for the keyboard shortcut. Any command that starts with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will take precedence over the single one that just uses <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> hence the reason it didn't work for me.

Keyboard shortcut search of <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd>:

[image: keyboard shortcut search of cmd + l]

Hope this helps anyone that may need clarification on this!

Comment: Just ran into this issue. Thanks for saving me time!

Comment: Thanks! Issue was actually specific to live sever.

Comment: Being unsure if I will ever need those same `Live Server` shortcuts added by *Go Live*, I preferred to simply double default `expandLineSelection` into `cmd` + `L`  `cmd` + `L`

Answer (score 13):

For VS Code 1.36 release, or greater, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to select the whole line, then, press <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to increase indent, or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> to decrease indent.

Comment: You can also just click anywhere on the line without selecting it, and increase/decrease the indent with `CTRL`+ `[` and `CTRL` + `]`

Answer (score 12):

I googled the same question but with the need to delete an entire line in a single keystroke. If you are in the same boat, the shortcut to delete the current line is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

Comment: And the difference between Ctrl+Shift-K and Ctrl-X (which both delete the current line) is that Ctrl-Shift-K does not mess with the clipboard so it remains with what was previously there - if that is what you want.  Although the question was about selecting...

Answer (score 10):

There are options to select an ***entire line*** or just the ***contents of a line*** as follows (Mac mappings):

- Select **Entire Line**:<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- Select **Contents of Line**: Place Cursor in line content then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (press right arrow twice)

If you want to assign your own keyboard shortcuts, in your shortcut preferences look for:

- **Entire Line**: `expandLineSelection`
- **Select Contents of Line**: `editor.action.smartSelect.expand`

(You can get to your Keyboard shortcuts by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)

As a bonus there's also a command to Shrink the Selection:

- **Shrink Selection**: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow)

Comment: Are there alternative for those that don't have command option?

Comment: @Shulz Are you on Windows? Use the Control (ctrl) key instead, if yes.

Answer (score 4):

The reason CMD+L is working may be that you have live server extension, it will create collision.
Disable it or remove it or modify the shortcuts of live server.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to **Preferences** → **Keyboard Shortcuts**
2. Search for "`expandLineSelection`" 
   Change Keybinding to any key you wish.
3. If you want to use <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> as default, just change it back.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling also with the same need, and my advice is:

Don't search for default **key combination** because those change from installation to installation unfortunately but, you have to option to search by **keyword** and then set the **key combination** you prefer the most:

The **keyword** to search the shortcut for selecting the whole current line is **cursorLineEndSelect**

[View from VScode Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTIA9.png)

Answer (score 0):

When the line is commented: (ctrl+k+c) on windows
If the line is not a comment: (ctrl+k+u) on windows