# Selecting line in Visual Studio 2017 with mouse clicks?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I think it was possible in previous version of VS to select a line with 3 consecutive clicks,

reference: [Is there any shortcut to select the current line in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159398/is-there-any-shortcut-to-select-the-current-line-in-visual-studio/19649222#19649222)

Is there a way to enable it in Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.4)?

Comment: Three clicks work for me in 15.7.6.

Comment: mine doesn't work