# How to select whole line in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode on a Mac.

**Does anyone know how to select the entire line that the cursor is on?** I know about <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, but that only selects what appears to be the whole line, which is not always the whole line if I have word wrap enabled.

I am looking for something like Sublime Text's "Expand Selection to Line" command.

Comment: VSCode does have "Expand Selection", but I don't use the standard keyboard shortcuts so I don't know what it's bound to by default - look in the command palette

Comment: I looked at the command palette, and the closest thing I could find is "expandLineSelection", which seems to do what Command+I does.

Comment: Same issue with "cut command". Not a priority for vscode dev team. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/138259/cut-command-should-delete-logical-line.html

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_shrinkexpand-selection

Comment: It's worth noting that many common commands (copy, cut, move line...) automatically apply to current line when there's no selection.

Answer (score 51):

All you need to do is put the cursor anywhere on the line, do not make any selection at all and then do the desired command (Cut, copy, or paste).

When no text selected, VS Code will automatically select the entire line.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to select more than one line? I can't just do it by repeatedly pressing Command+L like I can in Sublime Text.

Comment: What if you need to select this line?

Comment: @Qui-GonJinn what do you want when you select this line? 

If you want to clean that,  you can press `ctrl` + `shift` + `K`

I mean, you can do anything by hotkey, no need to select the whole line,  just do the command you want

Comment: This is different to triple-click and actually doesn't work in my case... I'm copying a powershell command from a file into command line... using this method, it copies something extra at the end so the command fails to work (includes \n with ">>"?) - not sure what's going on... but triple click works fine

Answer (score 19):

1. Triple click at any point on the line
2. Click once on number of the line
3. Press Command + L

Answer (score 16):

just *triple click* the end of the line it will select the entire line

Comment: Hmmm... I am able to select the end of the line by triple-clicking. Or by clicking the line number once. I was hoping to find a keyboard shortcut, but those shortcuts are helpful.

Comment: I hope that helps for the moment

Comment: ```Ctrl``` + ```L``` does the same thing on Visual Studio Code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62201527/8851276

Answer (score 6):

`Ctrl + L`  on **Windows** or `Command + L` on **Mac** to select the whole line in VS Code.

You can use your mouse to select the whole line by `triple-clicking on the line` but the better way is to `click on the line number` to select the whole line or multiple lines.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to what people have posted is, when your cursor is at the **start/end** of the line, you can hit <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>end</kbd>/<kbd>home</kbd> respectively.

I find this useful for wrapping a line in curly braces/quotes/etc. whereas the other answers include spaces in the select so whatever you're wrapping it in will be wrapped around that whitespace.

Comment: I do not think there are "home" and "end" keys on a mac, as [Two Mac keyboard shortcuts for missing Home and End keys](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/two-mac-keyboard-shortcuts-for-missing-home-and-end-keys/) would indicate.

Answer (score 2):

Install the [MetaGo extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=metaseed.metago) and use the "metaGo: selectLineDown" command, which will come installed already overriding the "expandLineSelection" command.

This extension has many additional commands that you'll likely find useful as well, including moving up/down over code blocks, centering the active line, and going to any character on the screen.

Comment: I'm a bit too busy to want to try an extension now, but I'll try it when I get a chance. When I asked this question, I thought there was just a simple setting in VSCode that I was overlooking.

Answer (score 2):

Now, when I press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, the whole line is selected. I am guessing this was caused by an update to VS Code, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Tripple click at any point on the line

Answer (score 1):

In case you're wondering why <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is not working, there might be a chance that there are duplicate shortcuts. You can find out by  opening Keyboard Shortcuts in VSC and remove the one that's not needed.

Comment: I learned how to display Keyboad shaped label by <kbd> tag

Answer (score 0):

I know its old but for anyone seeking, you can press **Alt + arrow up/down** to duplicate your cursor to other lines and then without selecting anything copy and paste multiple lines.