# Visual Studio - Keyboard-Shortcut: How do I select a line by shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2019

How do I select a line by shortcut?

My goal is e.g. to surround a specific code snippet with something like try/catch block:

<kbd>Select line Key</kbd> -> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> -> <kbd>s</kbd> -> <kbd>s</kbd> -> <kbd>t</kbd> -> <kbd>r</kbd> -> <kbd>y</kbd> -> <kbd>enter</kbd> -> baammm.

I found I could do <kbd>HOME</kbd> and then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd>, but the <kbd>HOME</kbd> and <kbd>END</kbd> button are far away. According to [Visual Studio Shortcut Description](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) (unstated to which version this is referencing to) it says <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

In my case (freshly downloaded VS without any changes made in any settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (i.e. Ctrl+Shift+l) is deleting the line, which is NOT selecting it. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> is then deleting the line keeping its contents in the cache which is very basically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

According to Mr_Green in [that similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159398/is-there-any-shortcut-to-select-the-current-line-in-visual-studio)) it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>U</kbd>, which doesn't work either.

And then I found this:
[Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4yjR.jpg)
Here I would think to find something like "Edit.SelectLine", but it's not there.

Comment: Literally looking for this... no idea why this is not in Visual Studio; it's in almost every other text editor. smh Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for Visual Studio 2022 there are now three commands usable in the context of a text editor:

- Edit.ExpandSelection (default: `Shift` + `Alt` + `+`)
- Edit.ExpandSelectiontoContainingBlock (default: `Shift` + `Alt` + `´`)
- Edit.ExpandSelectionToEntireLine (default: `Shift` + `Alt` + `E`)

For more information about subword selection/navigation see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77881259/2987814).

Comment: First two doesn't do anything on my VS 2022 (17.8.2). However THE THIRD POINT is the very thing I was looking for and 3 years and 10 months solved my issue!! A minor one, but an issue. Thank you very much Johnson!

Comment: @RadioMan Glad I could help. I began using VS 3 weeks ago and actually I was suprised to not immediately find an answer to that question myself. This seems to be such a core feature for any keyboard addicted programmer. If the first two shortcuts are not working, they are likely overwritten by an extension already or may not be defined at all for specific languages (I am using C#). See the link for information on how to set up these keyboard shortcuts in the options of VS.